# Не удается запустить локальный сервер в python/django

Tags: python, django

На днях произошла проблема с manage.py. Не могу какие либо провести манипуляции в терминале с ним, даже запустить сервер

```
(myvenv) $ ls
WorkBoard   db.sqlite3  myvenv      user
board       manage.py   pictures
(myvenv) $ python3 manage.py runserver
(myvenv) $ python3 manage.py makemigrations
(myvenv) $ python3 manage.py migrate
```

Comment: `./manage.py runserver`

Comment: такая же проблема, игнорирует